# How can I fully traverse a 5x5 grid in c++ to produce a path of the same length (25)?

Tags: c++, grid, traversal, path-finding

I am trying to fully traverse a grid and create a path while doing so.  I recursively enter a new cell (or Point), I would then move up, down, left, right until I reach all the cells in the grid.  In this example, I am traversing a 5x5 grid that should produce a path length of 25 every time.  When running this code, the path length at maximum gets up to 24 (many times found via logging statements).  Anyone see the issue of why I cannot fully traverse this grid properly to a path length of 25?

(Once I solve this logic issue, I do plan to add randomness to the traversing)

this code can be compiled and run out of the box via:

g++ main.cpp -o main

```
#include <vector>                                                                                                     
#include <list>                                                                                                       
#include <iostream>                                                                                                   

class Point {                                                                                                         
 public:                                                                                                              
  int x, y;                                                                                                           
  Point (int x, int y) : x (x), y (y) {}                                                                              
};                                                                                                                    

class TraverseGrid {                                                                                                  
 public:                                                                                                              
  TraverseGrid () { }                                                                                                 
  virtual ~TraverseGrid() {}                                                                                          
  void createPath (std::vector<Point>& path, const int& width, const int& height, Point start = Point (0, 1));        
 private:                                                                                                             
  bool recursiveFindPath (std::vector<Point>& path, int width, int height);                                           
  bool isValid (Point point, int width, int height);                                                                  
  bool inPath (std::vector<Point>path, Point point);                                                                  
};                                                                                                                    

void TraverseGrid::createPath (std::vector<Point>& path, const int& width, const int& height, Point start) {          
  path.push_back (start);                                                                                             
  bool result = recursiveFindPath (path, width, height);                                                              
  std::cout << "TraverseGrid result = " << result << " pathsize= " << path.size() << std::endl;                       
}                                                                                                                     

bool TraverseGrid::recursiveFindPath (std::vector<Point>& path, int width, int height) {                              
  if (path.size() == 24)                                                    
    std::cout << 24 << " found!" << std::endl;                         
  if (path.size() == static_cast<std::size_t>(width * height))                                                        
    return true;                                                                                                      
  std::list<Point> nextPoints;                                                                                        
  Point point = path.back();                                                                                          
  Point point1 (point.x - 1, point.y);                                                                                
  Point point2 (point.x + 1, point.y);                                                                                
  Point point3 (point.x, point.y - 1);                                                                                
  Point point4 (point.x, point.y + 1);                                                                                
  if (isValid (point1, width, height) && !inPath (path, point1))                                                      
    nextPoints.push_back (point1);                                                                                    
  if (isValid (point2, width, height) && !inPath (path, point2))                                                      
    nextPoints.push_back (point2);                                                                                    
  if (isValid (point3, width, height) && !inPath (path, point3))                                                      
    nextPoints.push_back (point3);                                                                                    
  if (isValid (point4, width, height) && !inPath (path, point4))                                                      
    nextPoints.push_back (point4);                                                                                    
  for (Point p : nextPoints) {                                                                                        
    path.push_back (p);                                                                                               
    if (recursiveFindPath (path, width, height))                                                                      
      return true;                                                                                                    
    path.pop_back();                                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                   
  return false;                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                     

bool TraverseGrid::isValid (Point point, int width, int height) {                                                     
  if (point.x < 0 || point.x >= width || point.y < 0 || point.y >= height)                                            
    return false;                                                                                                     
  return true;                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                     
bool TraverseGrid::inPath (std::vector<Point>path, Point point) {                                                     
  for (Point pathPoint : path) {                                                                                      
    if (point.x == pathPoint.x && point.y == pathPoint.y)                                                             
      return true;                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                   
  return false;                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                     

int main() {                                                                                                          
  TraverseGrid grid;                                                                                                  
  std::vector<Point> path;                                                                                            
  grid.createPath (path, 5, 5);                                                                                       
  std::cout << "path size = " << path.size() << std::endl;                                                            
  return 0;                                                                                                           
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: so why the C tag, is clearly c++

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I have been working on this for 2 days before I posted this question.

*This turned out to NOT be a debugging or coding question.  I did not have a correct understanding of grid traversal.

After debugging and stepping through the code and seeing what I expected, I realized the number of possible of path direction will take way too long to step through.  I wrote another function to print out the path as it was being made.  After looking at page after page of watching the path grow and then decend, I realized that my code was behaving as expected.  What I did not know, but came to figure out is that it is NOT always possible to be able to traverse a grid fully.  The below grid starting at "00" I discovered cannot be fully traversed via a path.  Code is working as expected.

It is NOT possible to fully traverse to all 25 cells (starting at 00)

```
|  |00|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | 
|  |  |  |  |  |
```

TraverseGrid method I used to display the grid with the path as it grows and decends.

```
void TraverseGrid::printVector (std::vector<Point>& path, int width, int height) {                                  
    std::cout << std::endl;                                                                                           
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {                                                                                 
      for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {                                                                              
        Point p (i, j);                                                                                               
        if (inPath (path, p))                                                                                         
          std::cout << "|" << getTrim(inPathIndex(path,p), 2);                                                        
        else                                                                                                          
          std::cout << "|  ";                                                                                         
      }                                                                                                               
      std::cout << "|" << std::endl;                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```